# Is there any physical example of a real closed system?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

Is there any physical example of a real closed system?

I am aware that the whole universe can be considered as a closed system, but I am looking for a smaller example.

Comment: The universe is an isolated system. A closed system is a system can interchange energy with surrounds but not matter. There are hundred of examples of closed systems in nature: bomb calorimeter, the Earth, a saucepan with lid (https://chem.libretexts.org/@api/deki/files/9934/closed1.png)

Comment: As long as there are photons there will never be a closed system.

Answer (score 1):

A "closed system" is an idealization, and obviously can't be *perfectly* realized in practice ; however a closed water bottle that you put in your fridge or microwave (very bad idea) would be a simple example.

Note that actually the whole universe would rather be considered an isolated system, since I don't see what it could exchange energy with.

Answer (score 1):

A *closed* system has no mass transfer in/out of the system, but can have energy transfer (heat and/or work) in/out of the system.  An *isolated* system has no mass transfer and no energy transfer in/out of the system.  The earlier comment by @Nicolas is correct.  See a good text on thermodynamics such as one by Sonntag and Van Wylen.

There are numerous real-world examples of a closed system as the comment by @juanrga states; for example a solid container filled with gas that is compressed by a piston that allows no mass transfer between the container (the closed system) and its surroundings.

I believe your question should be whether or not there exists a true isolated system.  An isolated system would have to be in perpetual thermal equilibrium with its surroundings and have no work done on/by the system.  I believe the universe is the only truly isolated system.

Answer (score 0):

A closed system in thermodynamics is defined as a system whose properties are not affected by the surrounding that is no flow of energy in or out of the system occurs. A simple example can be of a hot water bottle which is used to store hot liquids although it is not fully insulated due to which there is a little bit of exchange og energy between the liquid inside it and the surrounding, but it is the best example. If you imagine  of a hot water bottle which is fully insulated and no heat flow's outside it, you can say it to be closed system.

Comment: That would be an _isolated_ system. A _closed_ system can exchange work or heat, but not matter. [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermodynamic_system]

Comment: as i studied closed system or isolated system were same not too deep in the topic

Comment: @Nicolas is correct.  Please see my answer.